# Get a list of the lowest subdirectories in a tree

Tags: python, os.walk

I have a path to a certain directory, and I need to get a list of all of it's sub-directories that themselves don't contain any sub-directories.

For example, if I've got the following tree:

```
-father_dir:
    -son_dir1:
        -grandson.txt
    -son_dir2:
        -grandson_dir1:
            -greatgrandson1.txt
```

I'd like to have a list containing: `[son_dir1, grandson_dir1]`

What I tried: I used `os.walk()` to get all of the sub-directories in `father_dir`, and now I'm trying to iterate over each sub-directory's contents (with `os.listdir()`) and find if it contains directories... so far I wasn't successful (as `os.listdir()` doesn't give the path to the directory but rather only its name), besides it seems to be a very cumbersome method.

Any simple solution would be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
lowest_dirs = list()

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(starting_directory):
    if not dirs:
        lowest_dirs.append(root)
```

This works because `os.walk` recurses through the directories, setting each to `root` in turn. You want to know if it's a lowest-level directory? That means it contains no other directories, so for that root if `dirs` is empty, toss it in an accumulator.

If you additionally want to skip EMPTY lowest-level folders, do:

```
    if files and not dirs:
```

If you only want the tail (the folder name, not the whole path), use:

```
        lowest_dirs.append(os.path.split(root)[-1])
```

#### Test it:

```
>>> lowest_dirs = list()
>>> toplevel = r"U:\User\adsmith\My Documents\dump\father_dir"
>>> for root,dirs,files in os.walk(toplevel):
...     if not dirs:
...         lowest_dirs.append(os.path.split(root)[-1])
>>> print(lowest_dirs)
['son_dir1', 'grandson_dir1']
```

Comment: Beautiful (both the implementation and the explanation)! Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use `os.walk` and a list comprehension:

```
[os.path.split(r)[-1] for r, d, f in os.walk(tree) if not d]
```